# Does the rifleman perk affect semi-automatic weapons?

Tags: fallout-4

The rifleman perk (highlighted on the screenshot) says the following:

> Attacks with non-automatic rifles do 20% more damage.

[image]

Is this perk only invalid for fully-automatic weapons, or is it also invalid for semi-automatic weapons? Semi-automatic weapons are not explicitly mentioned in any perk, so I am not sure how they are handled.

Comment: downvote for asking if a perk that says "non-autmatic" affects automatic weapons.

Comment: @Dallium Except semi-automatic != automatic, and the perk does affect them.

Comment: @DCShannon you must not have seen the question before it was edited.

Comment: @DCShannon It's not obvious at all. If Unknown Zombie's edit had come up on my review queue, I would have rejected it for changing the intent of the question. I considered rolling it back.

Comment: On the one hand, yes, it was a typing mistake or less contemplated, on the other hand I suppose everybody knew what has been meant, namely if semi-automatic weapons are counted as fullautomatic weapons or non-automatic weapons regarding those perks :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Rifleman perk will increase the damage on any *Rifle-class* weapon that *will not* continually spray bullets while the trigger is held. This is valid for bolt-action type Hunting Rifles, semi-automatic weapons like the Laser Rifle, and even shotguns like the Double Barrel Shotgun.

A gun is considered to be a rifle when it has a full-sized stock.

Source is personal experience; the damage on my Laser Rifle goes up when I increase the level of this talent.

Comment: Just for a note this perk applies to shotguns also.

Comment: @Dupree3 Yes, that is true. Added it to the answer for completeness.

Comment: There is also a loading screen tip that mentions this perk and the guns you listed.

Answer (score 2):

For the purpose of perks, semi automatic weapons are basically single shot weapons (since they're not fully automatic and holding down fire only fires one shot).

This means that the Gunslinger perk for pistols and Rifleman perk for rifles apply.

Comment: Wait are you saying that both gunslinger and rifleman both increase the damage of semi-auto weapons?

Comment: Gunslinger for semi-auto pistols, Rifleman for semi-auto rifles